# Kubernetes hpa cpu utilization

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I found something wrong at HPA for istio gateway.

Why did 10m equal 10%? Wasn't 10m 1%?

Kubernetes version is 1.18.5.

```
# kubectl get hpa --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                   REFERENCE                         TARGETS   MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
istio-system   istio-egressgateway    Deployment/istio-egressgateway    7%/80%    2         10        2          13d
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   Deployment/istio-ingressgateway   10%/80%   2         10        2          21d
istio-system   istiod                 Deployment/istiod                 0%/80%    1         5         1          21d
qa2            graph                  Deployment/graph                  2%/50%    1         10        1          7h35m
qa2            member                 Deployment/member                 0%/50%    1         10        1          7h38m
```

```
# kubectl describe hpa istio-ingressgateway -n istio-system | grep "resource cpu"
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  10% (10m) / 80%

# kubectl describe hpa istio-egressgateway -n istio-system | grep "resource cpu"
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  7% (7m) / 80%

# kubectl describe hpa istiod -n istio-system | grep "resource cpu"
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  0% (3m) / 80%

# kubectl describe hpa graph -n qa2 | grep "resource cpu"
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  2% (24m) / 50%

# kubectl describe hpa member -n qa2 | grep "resource cpu"
  resource cpu on pods  (as a percentage of request):  1% (12m) / 50%
```

Comment: could you also share your hpa yaml

Comment: Sorry. I modified my question. Only gateway cpu percentage is strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These values are not the same, and they are not directly calculated from each other.

The value in percents is the target average utilization (corresponding to the `targetAverageUtilization` parameter), which is relative to the requested value.

The value in the brackets is the target average value (`targetAverageValue`), which is not measured in percents - this is an absolute raw value for the metric.

Comment: I figured out your answer. Request for istio-ingressgateway is 100m so that 10m/100m is 10%. And request for member and graph is 1(1000m).